# A conjecture on 'truncated joint moments' of binomial coefficients under binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, entropy, moments, binomial-distribution

This is similar in spirit to [Sum of squares of middle binomial sums or 'Truncated mean' of binomial coefficients under binomial distribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350671/sum-of-squares-of-middle-binomial-sums-or-truncated-mean-of-binomial-coefficie) but gives some total estimates. Though the other one was amenable to computations this by nature looks formidable. I do not have much intuition on how fast $f(m,n)$ can grow?

$\mu=1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$ holds.

$n<m$ holds.

> Is there a good bound for $$\log_2\Bigg({\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_{m/n}=-\sqrt{\mu n\ln n}}^{\sqrt{\mu n\ln n}}\binom{n}{\frac n2 +i_1}\dots\binom{n}{\frac n2 +i_{m/n}}}{\mathbb P(\frac n2+i_1)\dots\mathbb P(\frac n2+i_{m/n})}\Bigg)?$$

where $\mathbb P(\frac n2+i)$ is under bionmial distribution and thus is $\frac{\binom{n}{\frac n2 +i}}{2^n}$ and thus this expression is 'truncated joint moment $\binom{n}{\frac n2 +i_j}$ from $j\in\{1,\dots,{m/n}\}$'.

Clearly this is $m-f(m,n)$ (seen from similar nature of terms and bounds from [Sum of squares of middle binomial sums or 'Truncated mean' of binomial coefficients under binomial distribution](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350671/sum-of-squares-of-middle-binomial-sums-or-truncated-mean-of-binomial-coefficie)) for some function $f$. How fast can $f(m,n)$ grow?

**Conjecture**: $\exists c>1: f(m,n)>c\frac mn$.

**Question**: Can $c>c'\ln n$ hold in above at some $c'>1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP has changed the original question. This change invalidates my previous answer. The answer below is to the changed question.

For any natural $m$ and $n$ such that $m/n$ is also natural, the expression now to be bounded is 
\begin{equation}
 L:=\frac mn\,\log_2 T,
\end{equation}
where $T$ is just as in the question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350671/sum-of-squares-of-middle-binomial-sums-or-truncated-mean-of-binomial-coefficie/350720#350720). In the corresponding answer there, it was shown that 
$$\log_2T=n-\log_2\sqrt{(1+o(1))\pi n};$$
(the asymptotics everywhere here are as $n\to\infty$).
Hence,
$$L=m-\frac mn\,\log_2\sqrt{(1+o(1))\pi n}.$$

Comment: I was reading $\ln\sqrt n$ as $\sqrt{\ln n}$.

Answer (score 1):

For any natural $m$ and $n$ such that $m/n$ is also natural, the expression to be bounded is 
\begin{equation}
 L:=\frac mn\,\log_2(U_n/2^n),
\end{equation}
where 
\begin{equation}
 U_n:=\sum_{k\colon\,|k-n/2|\le u}\binom nk^3
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
 u:=\sqrt{\mu n\ln n}. 
\end{equation}
Letting 
\begin{equation}
 h_k:=\frac{k-n/2}{n/2}\quad\text{and}\quad t_k:=h_k\sqrt{2n}=\frac{k-n/2}{\sqrt{n/8}},
\end{equation} 
by Stirling's formula we have 
\begin{align}
 \binom nk&\sim\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n/2}}\exp\{-n[(1+h_k)\ln(1+h_k)+(1-h_k)\ln(1-h_k)]\} \\ 
 &\sim\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n/2}}\exp\{-n[h_k^2+O(h_k^3)]\} \\ 
& \sim\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n/2}}\exp\{-t_k^2/2\}; 
\end{align} 
everywhere here, the asymptotics are for $n\to\infty$ and $k$ such that $|k-n/2|\le u$.

Hence,
\begin{align*}
 U_n&\sim\frac{2^{3n}}{\pi^{3/2}n}\;\sum_{k\colon\,|t_k|\le u/\sqrt{n/8}}e^{-3t_k^2/2}(t_{k+1}-t_k) \\ 
 &\sim\frac{2^{3n}}{\pi^{3/2}n}\;\int_{|t|\le u/\sqrt{n/8}}e^{-3t^2/2}\,dt \\ 
 &\sim\frac{2^{3n}}{\pi n}\sqrt{\frac23}.  
\end{align*}
Here the transition from the sum to the integral is possible because $t_{k+1}^2-t_k^2=(t_{k+1}-t_k)(t_{k+1}+t_k)\le\frac1{\sqrt {n/8}}\,(2u/\sqrt{n/8}+\frac1{\sqrt{n/8}})=o(1)$.

So, 
\begin{align}
 L&=\frac mn\,\Big(2n+\log_2\Big(\frac1{(\pi+o(1)) n}\sqrt{\frac23}\,\Big)\Big) \\ 
 &=2m-\frac mn\,\log_2\frac{(\pi+o(1)) n}{\sqrt{2/3}}. 
\end{align}

Thus, your conjecture will hold if (and only if) you replace $m-f(m,n)$ by the correct expression $2m-f(m,n)$, with the main term $2m$ rather than $m$.

Comment: I think the quantity inside the logarithm is at most $2^m$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. If you look at the other problem I either had a square form or a moment form. I mixed the two and I removed the square now and so for this do we have $m-\Omega(\frac mn\ln n)$?

Comment: I see only $m\sqrt{\ln n}/n$ when combined with other problem. Perhaps $\ln n$ is not correct.

Comment: @VS. : You should not change the question so as to invalidate an answer, especially if the answer required a non-negligible effort. If you have any additional questions, you should ask them in separate posts. Anyway, I have now given an answer to the changed question as well. If any **specific step** in either answer is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I like your answer. Only thing I made a typo mistake from copying in problem. Essentially what happens if there are no squares?